# How to extract data from html response using python?

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract some of the data from an HTML response I'm getting after executing an API in Python. Here is the HTML response I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <mgmtResponse responseType="operation" requestUrl="https://6.7.7.7/motion/api/v1/op/enablement/ethernet/summary?deviceIpAddress=10.3.4.3" rootUrl="https://6.7.7.7/webacs/api/v1/op">
   <ethernetSummaryDTO>
     <CoredIdentityCapable>false</CoredIdentityCapable>
     <currentIcmpLatency>0</currentIcmpLatency>
     <deviceAvailability>100</deviceAvailability>
     <deviceName>TRP5504.130.Cored.com</deviceName>
     <deviceRole>Unknown</deviceRole>
     <deviceType>Cored TRP 5504</deviceType>
     <ipAddress>10.3.4.3</ipAddress>
     <locationCapable>false</locationCapable>
     <nrPortsDown>49</nrPortsDown>
     <nrPortsUp>16</nrPortsUp>
     <reachability>Reachable</reachability>
     <softwareVersion>7.8.1</softwareVersion>
     <stackCount>0</stackCount>
     <systemTime>2023-Apr-16, 12:47:51 IST</systemTime>
     <udiDetails>
       <description>TRP5500 4 Slot Single Chassis</description>
       <modelNr>TRP-5504</modelNr>
       <name>Rack 0</name>
       <productId>TRP-5504</productId>
       <udiSerialNr>FOX2304P14Z</udiSerialNr>
       <vendor>Cored Systems, Inc.</vendor>
       <versionId>V01</versionId>
     </udiDetails>
     <upTime>87 days 20 hrs 40 mins 27 secs</upTime>
   </ethernetSummaryDTO>
 </mgmtResponse>
```

Basically, I want to extract data like `deviceName`  and `softwareVersion`, and `udiSerialNr' from the HTML response. I tried the following code:

```
      if response.status_code == 200:
                #resp = response.text
                resp = response.json()
                api_resp = resp["ethernetSummaryDTO"]
                print(api_resp)
```

so I tried to convert it to JSON, but I end with below error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I parse this to extract the required data?

Comment: That `HTML` response is `XML` - now I am unfamiliar with Python but `resp = response.json()` seems incorrect for dealing with XML

Answer (score 0):

Please parse the response text as following

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

if response.status_code == 200:
    # resp = response.text
    resp = response.text
    parse_response(resp)
    
def parse_response(xml_string):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

    ethernet_summary = root.find('ethernetSummaryDTO')
    device_name = ethernet_summary.find('deviceName').text
    device_type = ethernet_summary.find('deviceType').text
    ip_address = ethernet_summary.find('ipAddress').text
    nr_ports_down = int(ethernet_summary.find('nrPortsDown').text)
    nr_ports_up = int(ethernet_summary.find('nrPortsUp').text)
    software_version = ethernet_summary.find('softwareVersion').text
    up_time = ethernet_summary.find('upTime').text

    data = {
        'device_name': device_name,
        'device_type': device_type,
        'ip_address': ip_address,
        'nr_ports_down': nr_ports_down,
        'nr_ports_up': nr_ports_up,
        'software_version': software_version,
        'up_time': up_time
    }

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your response (I will assign it to a variable, as if I've got it from an API call):

```xml
xml_data = '''<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <mgmtResponse responseType="operation" requestUrl="https://6.7.7.7/motion/api/v1/op/enablement/ethernet/summary?deviceIpAddress=10.3.4.3" rootUrl="https://6.7.7.7/webacs/api/v1/op">
   <ethernetSummaryDTO>
     <CoredIdentityCapable>false</CoredIdentityCapable>
     <currentIcmpLatency>0</currentIcmpLatency>
     <deviceAvailability>100</deviceAvailability>
     <deviceName>TRP5504.130.Cored.com</deviceName>
     <deviceRole>Unknown</deviceRole>
     <deviceType>Cored TRP 5504</deviceType>
     <ipAddress>10.3.4.3</ipAddress>
     <locationCapable>false</locationCapable>
     <nrPortsDown>49</nrPortsDown>
     <nrPortsUp>16</nrPortsUp>
     <reachability>Reachable</reachability>
     <softwareVersion>7.8.1</softwareVersion>
     <stackCount>0</stackCount>
     <systemTime>2023-Apr-16, 12:47:51 IST</systemTime>
     <udiDetails>
       <description>TRP5500 4 Slot Single Chassis</description>
       <modelNr>TRP-5504</modelNr>
       <name>Rack 0</name>
       <productId>TRP-5504</productId>
       <udiSerialNr>FOX2304P14Z</udiSerialNr>
       <vendor>Cored Systems, Inc.</vendor>
       <versionId>V01</versionId>
     </udiDetails>
     <upTime>87 days 20 hrs 40 mins 27 secs</upTime>
   </ethernetSummaryDTO>
 </mgmtResponse>'''
```

You can use the [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module to parse it.

For example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# The first element of your XML is the mgmtResponse, I'm directly getting it with [0]
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)[0]
softwareVersion = root.find("softwareVersion").text
deviceName = root.find("deviceName").text

# For the udiDetails attributes
udiDetails = root.find("udiDetails")
udiSerialNr = [det for det in udiDetails if det.tag == "udiSerialNr"][0].text
# and so on..
```

The last line to get `udiSerialNr` is a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) that is allowing to get the value directly from a loop, basically it's a for loop in one line, equivalent to:

```
udiDetails = root.find("udiDetails")
udiSerialNr = ""
for det in udiDetails:
    if det.tag == "udiSerialNr":
        udiSerialNr = det.text
```

Basically, in XML every node is a new list, so `mgmtResponse` is the first list (made of just one record, `ethernetSummaryDTO`, that's why I've directly set `ET.fromstring(xml_data)[0]` to fetch it).

`ethernetSummaryDTO` is the second list, but we don't iterate thought it, we use the `.find` method to get the attribute (eg `softwareVersion`).

`udiDetails` is just another list, I've used a for loop to get its attibutes, but I've just tried and we can use `.find()` again, which is making it easier, without unnecessary code:

```
udiDetails = root.find("udiDetails")
udiSerialNr = udiDetails.find("udiSerialNr").text
```

Way better!

Comment: in last line how did you initialize `udiDetails` ?

Comment: The last like is a list comprehension to directly get the value without writing the loop multi-line, let me update the answer as it would be difficult to add it to the comments..

Comment: Oops, I've forgotten to add `udiDetails = root.find("udiDetails")`, that wasn't helping in understanding I suppose :D

Comment: And eventually that comprehension isn't even required, my bad. Check the last part, you can use `.find` again which is way better :)